# error installing qt-sdk

Tags: qt

I tried to install qt-sdk, but every time while unpacking I receive an error Extract: error `Extract: error ... qtcreator-debug.ini` somebody knows why, thanks in advance

I have this file `qt-sdk-win-opensource-2010.04.exe` I'm working with `windows`

Comment: Operating system, sdk version? Is that the full error text?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure [TEMP is on C:](http://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTBUG-5940) and that you have enough free space.

Comment: what does it mean TEMP on C:, and is it possible to install this program on D: for example?

Comment: Look in C: for a TEMP folder. Create one if necessary.